# Facebook Graph API - temporary photos and scheduled posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am creating a facebook app that posts to a business Page (not a users own feed) and I am uploading photos to go along with my post. I am uploading the photo as opposed to providing a url for fetching.

I also want to schedule these posts up to two months in advance.

In [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v11.0/page/photos#Creating) of the facebook graph documentation it says "After you upload an unpublished photo, Facebook stores it in a temporary upload state, which means it will remain on Facebook servers for about 24 hours. If you do not publish these photos within 24 hours, we delete them."

Does this mean that I need to publish my photos in order to use them with scheduled posts? ie, if I upload an image and set it to unpublished, but then use it in a scheduled post that is scheduled for 5 days from now, will the photo be deleted before the post is posted?